# unable to dismiss side menu using delegate method in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, side-menu

So, basically, I implemented a SideMenu using the module side menu from pod. however, I am stuck at the last part where when I tapped on any of the options inside the menu, the side menu shall dismiss itself and display corresponding content depending on which menu option I picked.

my code for my main view controller is below:

class Profile: UIViewController, MenuControllerDelegate {

```
var menu: SideMenuNavigationController?
var menuController:MenuListController!
```

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    menu = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: MenuListController())
    menu?.leftSide = true
    menu?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    
    SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = menu
    SideMenuManager.default.addPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.view)
    setupNavBaritem()
}

func handleMenuToggle(menuOption: String?) {
    print("menuToggle function reached")
    menu?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func setupNavBaritem() {
    let menuicon = UIImage(named: "menu")
    let menubtn = UIButton(type: .system)
    menubtn.setImage(menuicon, for: .normal)
    menubtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menubtn)
    menubtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menubtntapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}

@objc func menubtntapped(){
    present(menu!,animated:true)
}
}
```

then this is my menu controller:

class MenuListController:UITableViewController {

```
var menuitems = ["1","2","3","4"]
var delegate:MenuControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "menucell")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuitems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menucell", for: indexPath) as! MenuCell
    let menuetext = menuitems[indexPath.row]
    let menuicon = menuimg[indexPath.row]
    cell.setmenucell(iconimg: menuicon, text: menuetext)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedMenu = menuitems[indexPath.row]
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    delegate?.handleMenuToggle(menuOption: selectedMenu)
}
```

}

and this is my protocol:

protocol MenuControllerDelegate {

```
func handleMenuToggle(menuOption:String? )
```

}

New updates!
with the delegate setup, i am able to reach the toggle function and print("menuToggle function reached"). but my dismiss doesnt work. i have been searching for a while and seems a lot of ppl are having trouble using the dismiss function to dismiss this sidemenu. any workaround that may work on this? i tried a few, including setting the new root controller, which didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i missed the delegate in this function

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedMenu = menuitems[indexPath.row]
    let temp = Profile()
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.delegate = temp
    delegate?.handleMenuToggle(menuOption: selectedMenu)
}
```

now, i can print out my menutoggle function!

Answer (score 0):

Change the frame of the centeController on delegate call. Set 0 when you want to dismiss.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.width - 80
            }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: are you refering to my handlemenutoggle func inside my delegate? i think the problem is that the print statement inside my handleMenuToggle func is never reached lol nothing gets printed when i click on individual cell in my menu.

Comment: @Jason Yin Call handleMenuToggle on through delegates